# Unable to get custom customer data in a standard manner?

Tags: custom-attributes, magento-2.2.5

I have added few custom attributes and one of them is `is_mobile_verified` while registering I dont set any value for this however, while creating the attribute I set default value as 0.

now after registration, I am trying to get the value to do some other functionalities. I am facing issues at this point.

```
        $customer_id = 39; // SETTING SOME ID FOR TESTING PURPOSE
        $is_verified = $customer->getCustomAttribute('is_mobile_verified')->getValue();
```

If I get the value using this code I am getting error message as below

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Because there is no value updated to this fields so for. Once from the admin section if I updated as `0` Then it returns the value.

Is there a way to restrict this behavior as in the earlier scenario also, if there is no value exist I can get empty value. Apparently this is what the actual behavior in `Magento1.x`

Comment: Can you update the full code as your code shows you have not loaded customer?

Answer (score 1):

If the custom attribute of the customer has no value, you should check like this before getting value of it:

```
    $customAttribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('is_mobile_verified');
    if (!$customAttribute) {
        return '';
    }

    return $customAttribute->getValue();
```

Basically, the custom attribute value will be saved when you set a specific value
to it and then save the customer. So to prevent the issue in case your custom attribute is not set, you should add a condition to verify it before use **getValue()** function

Cheers

Comment: Yes, I know this is one way. but in earlier `Magento1.x` we dont need to do a check like this,  `$customAttribute = $customerObj->getIsMobileVerified();` itself will return data if exists or empty value. Not an error. I am just looking is there a default `Magento2` function to meet this

Comment: You should do this way in Magento2.